# hover case when move ( on video )

Tags: css, hover, twitter-bootstrap-3

**index.html**

```
<!-- HEADER -->
<header class="top-header" id="home">

    <div class="container">


   <div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-3">

    <h1 class="logo hidden-xs"><a href="#top" class="text-hide center-block">Portfolio Page of Burak Aydin</a></h1>

            </div> <!-- end col-sm-3 -->

            <div class="col-sm-9">

                <nav class="navbar" role="navigation">

                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="#top" class="home">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#about" class="about">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#portfolio" class="portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#contact" class="contact">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>

                </nav>

            </div> <!-- end col-sm-9 -->

        </div> <!-- end row -->

    </div> <!-- end container -->


</header>
```

---

**styles.css**

```
nav.navbar {background-color:transparent;}
ul.nav {padding-top:1em;}
ul.nav li {text-transform: uppercase;font-weight:bold;}
ul.nav li a {-webkit-transition: color .3s ease-in-out; transition: color .3s ease-in-out;}
ul.nav li a:hover,ul.nav li a:active,
ul.nav li a:after{background-color:transparent;color:#ff6760;}
```

---

First of all I had used twitter bootstrap 3.

1. These problems happen on mozilla and IE's any version. When I hover over the menu and then if I move bottom right, you'll see a gray background behind the menu link.
2. When you click photo of portfolio section, you will see a pop-up. There is text decoration. I don't want text decoration.

This issue to mention is tough. So I uploaded a video. Here it is:
issue that I mention on this site:[LINK](http://www.screenr.com/KrjH)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the scaffolding.less there is a:hover and a:focus that underlines and turns into to the primary color set in the LESS variables.

```
a:hover,
a:focus {
  color: #2a6496;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

So if you want to remove it, do the following:

```
.my-container-with-content a:hover, .my-container-with-content a:focus {
text-decoration:none;
}
```

If the entire contents are in a wrapper such as ( a > div ):

So if you want to remove it, do the following:

```
a:hover .my-container-with-content,  a:focus .my-container-with-content {
text-decoration:none;
}
```

Make sure this CSS is after the Bootstrap CSS. Name "my-container-with-content" the class of the container that has the hover/focus that you want to remove.

Comment: thanks friend. it helped to me that you mentioned first.